# Who to append php on chnage with Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to append php script to the dom in a div that has the class .new-session but it doesn't work how it should.

Here is my code

```js
$('select[name=quantity]').change(function() {
  quantity = $(this).val();

  if (quantity == 20) {
    newSession = '<?php echo $_SESSION[\'product\'][\'quantity\'] = 20; ?>';
  }
  elseif(quantity == 30) {
    newSession = '<?php echo $_SESSION[\'product\'][\'quantity\'] = 30; ?>';
  }
  elseif(quantity == 40) {
    newSession = '<?php echo $_SESSION[\'product\'][\'quantity\'] = 40; ?>';
  }
  elseif(quantity == 50) {
    newSession = '<?php echo $_SESSION[\'product\'][\'quantity\'] = 50; ?>';
  }
  elseif(quantity == 60) {
    newSession = '<?php echo $_SESSION[\'product\'][\'quantity\'] = 60; ?>';
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "/multisite/",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(newSession) {
      $('.set-session').append(newSession);
    }
  })

});
```

```html
<div class="set-session">

</div>
```

Comment: use `console.log(newSession)` if there's a data passing back to the client

Comment: Why are you setting `newSession` in the Javascript, then using the same variable as the response from the PHP? Why aren't you sending a `data:` parameter in the AJAX call?

Comment: You can't append a PHP script to the DOM. PHP runs on the server, the DOM is processed on the client. You need to run the PHP on the server, and it should return the HTML that you append to the DOM. Your code is totally backwards.

Comment: Is this just for debugging or do you actually want to execute that `php` code? Also explain "doesn't work how it should.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't append PHP to the DOM, PHP code is run on the server when the page is being created. You use AJAX to run server code in response to a user action, and the script that receives the AJAX call updates the session.

Here's how you can do what you want:

```
$('select[name=quantity]').change(function() {
    var quantity = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/multisite/setquantity.php",
        data: { quantity: quantity }
    });
});
```

The PHP in `setquantyt.php` should be like:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['product']['quantity'] = intval($_GET['quantity']);
```